# Create virtual urls

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a single page application where different actions can be performed with different virtual urls (I mean not real urls in this context). These urls should be shareable via social networks.

I want to get the same result as with ember.js, but the problem is that the browser (Chrome in my case) resolves the address to a non-virtual one.

Example:
This is what I want:
`http://mysite.com/#/page1`

This is what I get after entering the above address:
`http://mysite.com/page1`

The problem is there is no folder like page1 in my application, it should represent a route like ember.js

I've already tried different approaches like History.js and location.hash, but I always end up with the same result.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you have code in which your URL gets redirected? Because it should just work like `http://mysite.com/#/page1`. Also good to have a look at HTML5 History API.

Comment: Agreed, this is a redirect happening.

Comment: ok thanks. history.js was responsible for the redirection.